# Python library to extract data from wikipedia?

Tags: python

What library do people use to extract data from Wikipedia pages?

I see [python-wikitools](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/p/python-wikitools/&ei=NkLiTv3WMuWqiAKNxdiDDw&usg=AFQjCNHbAPu0i5fEj24daBBAypxhfC93Xw&sig2=WF0bmXK1YPCyip2xtZCO7g), but the API confuses me.

Comment: It would help if you would clarify then which type of functionality you are after, rather than just saying "this one no". :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a list of Python libraries which interact with Wikipedia on the [*Creating a bot* page at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCreating_a_bot#Python).

Answer (score 1):

there is [mwclient](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mwclient/)

worth looking